# Testing Material components as a child component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, jasmine, mat-stepper

I have some component `TestComponent` that, in it's template, uses a `<mat-stepper>`. Because of the context of the stepper, I have to programmatically advance to the next step rather than using the `matStepperNext` directive on a button. So my component looks like this:

**test.component.ts**

```js
import { MatStepper } from '@angular/material/stepper'; //module loaded elsewhere, but is accesible

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  template: '<mat-stepper #stepper>
               <mat-step>
                 <button (click)="completeStep()">Next</button>
               </mat-step>
               <mat-step></mat-step> <!-- etc. -->
             </mat-stepper>',
})
export class TestComponent {
  @ViewChild('stepper') stepper!: MatStepper;

  completeStep() {
    this.stepper.next();
  }
}
```

Now the trick is that I have to test that `stepper.next()` was called. Because I'm just using the `<mat-dialog>` directive, I never actually create an object of it in the class, nor is it a provider in the constructor, so I'm not really sure how to test it. I've tried a bunch of different things with no success, and my latest test is as follow:

**test.component.spec.ts**

```js
describe('TestComponent', () => {
  let component: TestComponent,
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestCompnent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.ConfigureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TestComponent],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  describe('completeStep', () => {
    it('should call stepper.next', () => {
      const stepperSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('MatStepper', ['next']);
      component.stepper = stepperSpy;
      component.completeStep();
      expect(stepperSpy.next).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

But I just get the error

> Expected spy MatStepper.next to have been called

Answer (score 0):

In before each add MatStepper to declarations array:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
  await TestBed.ConfigureTestingModule({
       declarations: [TestComponent, MatStepper],
  }).compileComponents();
});
```

And the test case should look like:

```
it('completeStep should call stepper.next', () => {     
   jest.spyOn(component.stepper, 'next');
   component.completeStep();
   expect(component.stepper.next).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```